# Query about proof that order topology is compact if complete

Tags: general-topology, proof-explanation

In part 7 of example 39 in [Steen & Seebach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counterexamples_in_Topology), they try to prove that if an order topology on $X$ is complete (i.e. every non-empty subset of $X$ has a greatest lower bound and a least upper bound) then it is compact.

The proof proceeds in the following way:

Given an open cover $\mathcal{U}$, let $a=inf(X)$ (the greatest lower bound of $X$), and let $S=$ the elements $y\in X$ such that $[a,y)$ has a finite subcover in $\mathcal{U}$.
If $\alpha=sup(S)$ (the least upper bound of $S$), and if $\alpha\in U\in\mathcal{U}$ then $U\subset S$ .... (full proof can be found [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Linearly_Ordered_Space_is_Compact_iff_Complete))\

I don't understand that last statement, why does it follow that $U\subset S$?
In fact why does it even follow that $\alpha\in S$?
What am I missing, or have I uncovered a flaw in the proof?

The proof can also be seen here on proofwiki: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Linearly_Ordered_Space_is_Compact_iff_Complete \

Comment: If $\alpha \in U \in \mathcal{U}$ then take any $x \in U$, we cand find some $y \in U \cap S$ (since $\alpha = \sup S$), then $[a,y)$ can be covered by $(U_i)_{i=0}^m$ (each $U_i \in \mathcal{U}$), hence $[a,x)$ can be covered with $(U_i)_{i=0}^m $ plus $U$.

Comment: @DonaldW.Johnson I suggest that you post this solution as an answer so that it is clear that the question has been answered. One technical remark though - it is not enough that $y \in U \cap S$. Instead $y$ should be in an interval around $\alpha$ contained in $U$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Adayah has suggested and corrected above, here's a text with a little more details: First we show that $ \alpha \in S $. If $\alpha \in U \in \mathcal{U}$ we can find some $ z\in X $ such that the interval $ (z,\alpha] \subseteq U$, then since $ \alpha = \sup S $ we will find some $ y \in (z,\alpha] \cap S$. This $ y  $ satisfies that $ [a,y) $ can be covered by some finite subcover of $ \mathcal{U} $, say $ (U_i)_{i=0}^m $. I claim that $ [a,\alpha) $ can be covered with $ \{U,U_0,\dots,U_m\} $. Take any $ x \in[a,\alpha) $ then there are two possible cases: $ x\leq y $ or $ x\in (y,\alpha) $, in the first one is trivial to see that $ x \in\bigcup \{U,U_0,\dots,U_m\}   $ so suppose that  $ x \in (y,\alpha) $, then $ x\in (z,\alpha)\subseteq U $. We can then say that $ \alpha \in S $. So if $ U \not \subseteq S $ then we can find some $ p \in U-S $, the argument above shows that $ p $ must be greater than $ \alpha $, then there exists some $ u<\alpha <v $ such that $ (u,v)\subseteq U $ but then $ v \in S $ and is greater than $ \alpha $, which is impossible. We conclude that $ U\cap \{x \in X : x >\alpha\} = \emptyset$. And hence $ U \subseteq \{x \in X: x \leq \alpha\} \subseteq S$.

Comment: Aha.. thankyou! It seems kind of obvious now considering the definition of S. For the benefit of others; one slight wrinkle is the possibility that we could have $y=\alpha$ on line 3 of your proof, but in this case $(y,\alpha)$ will be empty so we must have $x\le y$, and the proof still works.